# Monitoring Outbound Message Queue

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Is there a way we can programatically monitor outbound message queue, say for e.g. I want an email notification when any of the below happens

1. I have more than x number of messages waiting on the outbound message queue
2. Any message sitting in the queue for more than x number of hours